# C# Json.NET - Prefix property names based on another property

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to serialize an object where the property names are prefixed based on another property in the object. This property will have a dynamic value at runtime, so I can't use the `JsonProperty` attribute. For example:

```
public class Example
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Prefix { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

```
var fooExample = new Example
{
    Prefix = "foo_"
};

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fooExample);
```

Output:

```
{
    foo_Name: ...
    foo_Value: ...
}
```

I tried to use a `ContractResolver` and override the `CreateProperty` method, however there doesn't seem to be a way to get a reference to the parent object from here in order to retrieve the value of the `Prefix` property. Is there any other way to achieve this with Json.NET?

```
protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

    // How do I get this value from another property in the parent object?
    string prefix = "";

    property.PropertyName = prefix + property.PropertyName;

    return property;
}
```

Comment: A simple way to do this would be to use a dictionary instead of a class and just add the keys to the dictionary with the desired prefix before serializing the dictionary. You can also use a dynamic object but that would likely be overkill for what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

just add a constructor

```
var fooExample = new Example
    {
        Prefix = "foo_", Name="name", Value="value"
    };
    
  
    var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fooExample,
                                        Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = 
                                 new PrefixSerializeContractResolver(fooExample.Prefix) });


public class PrefixSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly string _prefix;
     
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
    
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        property.PropertyName= _prefix+ property.PropertyName;

        return  property;
    }
    
    public PrefixSerializeContractResolver(string Prefix)
    {
     _prefix=Prefix;
    }
}
```

output

```
{
  "foo_Name": "name",
  "foo_Value": "value"
}
```

It is just a hint. You can improve the code by  creating a model class interface with  a Prefix property and a generic function. But it will be your home work.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom service that utilizes the JSON.NET `JsonWriter` and explicitly write the logic for converting an instance of a specific class (or something generic for any class) to a JSON string, controlling which the name of each property `WritePropertyName(String)` based on your prefix passed in or provided as a property on the target class.  With that approach you'd have complete control over the JSON serialization process for the class.  The service could be made to be generic so that it could be utilized on any of your classes that decorated/marked with an interface you create (e.g. `ICustomJsonKeySerializationPrefix`) that contain the property used for sourcing the prefix.